# Difference in size of Mpegts to sum of ts files

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to find the size of the transcoded asset, but I find that the sum of the sizes of the .ts files doesn't match that of the mpegts output file created by ffmpeg.

For example:

With source of 5Mb I get the following output

```
/ffmpeg -y -i big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4 -s 854x480 -ss 0  -vcodec libx264 -level:v 3.0 -profile:v baseline -f mpegts -async 2 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -r 24.00 -b:v 703k -maxrate 703k -bufsize 703k -r 24.00 -b:a 96.0k test.mpegts -hls_time 10 -hls_segment_filename test-%03d.ts -hls_playlist_type vod test.m3u8
```

Size of test.mpegts -> 3.1Mb,
Sum of the size of ts files -> 5.5Mb

With source of 30Mb I get the following output

```
./ffmpeg -y -i big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4 -s 854x480 -ss 0  -vcodec libx264 -level:v 3.0 -profile:v baseline -f mpegts -async 2 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -r 24.00 -b:v 703k -maxrate 703k -bufsize 703k -r 24.00 -b:a 96.0k test1.mpegts -hls_time 10 -hls_segment_filename test-%03d.ts -hls_playlist_type vod test.m3u8
```

Size of test.mpegts -> 19Mb,
Sum of the size of the ts files -> 17Mb

With source of 63Mb I get the following output

```
./ffmpeg -y -i BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4 -s 854x480 -ss 0  -vcodec libx264 -level:v 3.0 -profile:v baseline -f mpegts -async 2 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -r 24.00 -b:v 703k -maxrate 703k -bufsize 703k -r 24.00 -b:a 96.0k test2.mpegts -hls_time 10 -hls_segment_filename test-%03d.ts -hls_playlist_type vod test.m3u8
```

Size of test.mpegts -> 62.21Mb
Sum of the size of the ts files -> 26Mb

With source of 397Mb I get the following output

```
./ffmpeg -y -i big_buck_bunny_720p_h264.mov -s 640x360 -ss 0  -vcodec libx264 -level:v 3.0 -profile:v baseline -f mpegts -async 2 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -r 24.00 -b:v 703k -maxrate 703k -bufsize 703k -r 24.00 -b:a 96.0k test3.mpegts -hls_time 10 -hls_segment_filename test-%03d.ts -hls_playlist_type vod test.m3u8
```

Size of test.mpegts -> 62Mb
Sum of the size of the ts files -> 142Mb

Source locations of files ->

```
http://www.sample-videos.com/


http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/
```

Can anybody point me to any documentation which explains why there is so huge variance in the difference of size between the .mpegts file and the sum of the .ts files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your encoding settings only apply to the `.mpegts` output. In ffmpeg, all output options, other than global ones, only apply to the next specified output.

The HLS streams are generated by a parallel encoding pipeline, and since you have provided no switches, use default values e.g. vcodec profile `high`, audio bitrate `128k`. Either copy over all encoding parameters to the 2nd output chain, or use the [tee](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee-1) muxer.

Comment: You mean to say 
/ffmpeg -y -i big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4 -s 854x480 -ss 0  -vcodec libx264 -level:v 3.0 -profile:v baseline -f mpegts -async 2 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -r 24.00 -b:v 703k -maxrate 703k -bufsize 703k -r 24.00 -b:a 96.0k test.mpegts -vcodec libx264 -level:v 3.0 -profile:v baseline -f mpegts -async 2 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -r 24.00 -b:v 703k -maxrate 703k -bufsize 703k -r 24.00 -b:a 96.0k -hls_time 10 -hls_segment_filename test-%03d.ts -hls_playlist_type vod test.m3u8 , this should generate same size for mpegts and sum of the ts files ?

Comment: You have to add `-s` and `-ss` as well. But otherwise, a qualified yes. There may still be a difference in keyframe selection.

Comment: the default keyint is 30, so that should remain the same.

Comment: Also you mean to say for the individual ts if I run mediainfo I will get vcodec mpeg2video and acodec mp2 ?

Comment: You should get the default codecs for HLS whatever they are. Since the default for TS is mpeg2video/mp2, I assume that's the case,

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have another question the suggestion you gave transcodes twice and takes double the time, can you suggest how output of one can be used as input of another ?  The command below works, but I need a named output such as test.mpegts

Comment: ./ffmpeg -y -benchmark -i big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4 -s 854x480 -ss 0  -vcodec libx264 -level:v 3.0 -profile:v baseline -f mpegts  -async 2 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -r 24.00 -b:v 703k -maxrate 703k -bufsize 703k -r 24.00 -b:a 96.0k -  | ./ffmpeg -i - -f hls  -s 854x480 -ss 0  -vcodec libx264 -level:v 3.0 -profile:v baseline  -async 2 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -r 24.00 -b:v 703k -maxrate 703k -bufsize 703k -r 24.00 -b:a 96.0k  -hls_time 10 -hls_segment_filename test-%03d.ts -hls_playlist_type vod test.m3u8

Comment: You'll have to use the [tee](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs#Teepseudo-muxer) muxer.

Comment: I havent been successful in using the tee muxer , can you please give an example.